# How to change background color of elements every 5s using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

Would like to ask for help regarding this one. I made 4 boxes with 2 background colors (red & green) without using html.

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2bk1Ldg2/3/

How can I make a way to identify the existing background color css to change it alternately within 5sec (red to green & green to red).

Didn't know what's the best query to search regarding this kind of problem. Your awesome answers are a big help to my learning. Appreciate it a lot!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function() {
    $( ".div1, .div3" ).animate({backgroundColor: 'red'
  }, 5000)};
});
```

Comment: Toggle a class instead and hanlde animation in CSS... http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: You didn't know what to search?... just put your title in Google

Comment: Your demo has syntax error. I fixed it in https://jsfiddle.net/2bk1Ldg2/4/ . Now, you want to change color of all divs every 5s?

Comment: @Mohammad yeah. the existing red turns to green and green to red in every 5sec

Comment: @Mohammad yow bro, would like to ask about this kind of approach. background change based from the background color of their previous element.

So let's say:

First box: red
Second box: blue
Third box: green
Fourth box: yellow

Then after 5 seconds the colors of the boxes should be like this:

First box: yellow
Second box: red
Third box: blue
Fourth box: green

Comment: @KobeBryan I think that is good question. I can answer to it but that is bettor to asking new question that i and another user see it and answer to it.

Comment: @Mohammad it's the same concept but another kind of approach. from 2 colors to 4 colors. they will still mark it as duplicate

Comment: @KobeBryan See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40087888/5104748

Comment: @Mohammad thank you so much bro! i hope you could be my mentor in jquery.

Comment: @Mohammad bro see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40254911/how-to-slide-an-element-using-jquery/ ...how can I make the slide smoother without reducing the size of the element? jsfiddle.net/3me0cvsa/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to repeat your code for seconds. Because you added `background` of element in `style` attribute, you can use [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) to get name backgroud color.

```
setInterval(function(){  
    $("div").each(function(){
        this.style.background = this.style.background == "green" ? "red" : "green";
    });
}, 5000);
```

```js
setInterval(function(){  
  $("div").each(function(){
    this.style.background = this.style.background == "green" ? "red" : "green";
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
div { height: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: green"></div>
<div style="background: red"></div>
<div style="background: green"></div>
<div style="background: red"></div>
```

Comment: The code is good but there's something wrong in it. Maybe you forgot to make an if condition. @Mohammad

Comment: @EricoTimbang No, one line code in `.each()` is condition. That is [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I see. I've noticed that the interval will just activate when it's green. If it is red, it will wait for the other boxes to turn green first. https://jsfiddle.net/2bk1Ldg2/6/ 

Thank you very much for your help @Mohammad! Appreciated it a lot!

Comment: @EricoTimbang Problem is in `line 4` of your code. You add `background-color` to element that shoud be `background`. See https://jsfiddle.net/2bk1Ldg2/7/