# How to set background color of every item to next item using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I have a list has 4 item and every item has specific background color that setted in style attribute.

```
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

I want to set background color of every item to next item. The above html should changed to

```
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>  
</div>
```

I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(".list > div").each(function(i){
  var index = i == 0 ? 3 : i-1;
  this.style.background = $(".list > div").eq(index)[0].style.background;
});
```

The code set color of last item to all items. What is problem?

```js
setInterval(function(){  
  $(".list > div").each(function(i){
    var index = i == 0 ? 3 : i-1;
    this.style.background = $(".list > div").eq(index)[0].style.background;    
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.list > div { height: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for asking and answering yourself exactly at the same time?!

Comment: @Dekel Yes, [share your knowledge](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Doesn't sound like a worth "self-answering" question, but maybe it's only me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem of code is that in `.each()` javascript set color of last item to first item and then set this color to another items. See bottom list that is example of loop:

- Item1: changed to color of `item4` that is `yellow`
- Item2: changed to color of `item1` that is `yellow`
- Item3: changed to color of `item2` that is `yellow`
- Item4: changed to color of `item3` that is `yellow`

Then color of all items changed to yellow.

You should store colors of items before changing and then change color of every item using stored colors.

```js
setInterval(function(){  
  var colors = $(".list > div").map(function(){
    return this.style.background;
  }).get();
  $(".list > div").each(function(i){    
    var index = i == 0 ? 3 : i-1;
    this.style.background = colors[index];
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.list > div { height: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution is better (mostly because you don't really need to know the number of child-elements).

Just take the last element in the array and move it to be the first one. Then - set the colors for each of the child-elements, one by one.

```js
setInterval(function(){  
  var colors = $(".list div").map(function(){
    return this.style.background;
  }).get();
  colors.unshift(colors.pop())
  
  $(".list div").each(function(i){    
    this.style.background = colors[i];
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.list > div { height: 50px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
  <div style="background: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've posted your own answer already, I thought I'd offer a slight alternative which requires only plain JavaScript (albeit ES6) which performs the same functionality:

```
// setting the enclosed anonymous function to run repeatedly,
// with the interval duration as the second argument, in
// milliseconds, following the anonymous function:
setInterval(function() {

  // retrieving the relevant elements, converting the result of
  // document.querySelectorAll() into an arry, using Array.from():
  let children = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list > div')),

  // retrieving an array of the background-colours of those
  // found elements, using Array.prototype.map() to create a
  // new array from the Array supplied:
    colors = children.map(

      // here we use an arrow function, 'child' is the current
      // array element of the array over which we're iterating

      // window.getComputedStyle(child,null) retrieves the
      // computed CSS properties of the child element, and
      // the backgroundColor property retrieves the current
      // background-color (whether defined in a stylesheet,
      // or in the style attribute):
      child => window.getComputedStyle(child, null).backgroundColor
    );

  // here we use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the
  // children array:
  children.forEach(function(child, index, array) {
    // child: the current array-element of the array
    //        over which we're iterating,
    // index: the index of the current array-element,
    // array: a reference to the array over which we're
    //        iterating.

    // here we set the background-color of the current
    // element to the returned index-value of the
    // expression
    child.style.backgroundColor = colors[

      // index + 1: the 'next' index value,
      // %: the remainder operator,
      // array.length: the length of the current array

      // here we increment the index by 1, we then
      // divide that number by the length of the array;
      // if the index is 0 that gives:
      //   (0+1)%4 = 1,
      //   (1+1)%4 = 2,
      //   (2+1)%4 = 3,
      //   (3+1)%4 = 0
      // we retreive the color held at the returned value
      // in the colors Array and set that as the
      // background-color of the current element:
      (index + 1) % array.length
    ];
  });
}, 1000);
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let children = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list > div')),
    colors = children.map(child => window.getComputedStyle(child, null).backgroundColor);

  children.forEach(function(child, index, array) {
    child.style.backgroundColor = colors[(index + 1) % array.length];
  });
}, 1000);
```

```css
.list > div {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div style="background: red">One</div>
  <div style="background: blue">Two</div>
  <div style="background: green">Three</div>
  <div style="background: yellow">Four</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`%` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).